How do I preprocess a Linux source?
I'm developing a Linux kernel module, mostly based off of info from https://github.com/sysprog21/lkmpg. (The Makefile for their examples: https://github.com/sysprog21/lkmpg/blob/master/examples/Makefile)
While they provide info on how to build them, I'm curious as to what a convenient way of obtaining just the preprocessor output(s) would be.

make KCPPFLAGS=--save-temps will generate a bunch of .i and .s files from the .c files during the build, but it's hard to get rid of them afterwards, so use a temporary build directory.

@IanAbbott Thank you very much. That did it. If you decide to post it as an answer, (which you should to make it more straightforward for future havers of this problem to find a solution) I will upvote and accept ;-).
